# Dumping data from view to excel

Tags: sql-server, mssql-tools

In a database one view is there,every day that view updted with adding one new column,now i want to design a ssis package to dump that data into excel sheet each day with seperate sheet. Can anyone please help me out of this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I recommend you try using ODBC. Connect to your view via ODBC (Data -> From Other Sources ->From SQL Server) in Excel, and it will refresh, every time time data in DB is refreshed.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301542/Creating-Excel-File-and-ExcelSheets-dynamically-fr

Comment: Is the new column name and it’s data type added each day to the view predictable?